# tomcat homepage is opening but 404 on any project that i have made (in eclipse helios)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I have started a project in JSP, I am using eclipse Helios 3.6 and tomcat 6.0 integration with it, the problem is that , when i start the tomcat server from eclipse , it starts normally (Means the hompage is displaying on "localhost:8085"), but when i make a "new dynamic web project" (even very simple project that just display index.html in "web-content" folder) I got a 404 not found error. **The directory structure is as follows**

[image]
I am accessing the project through "localhost:8085/testing", but it shows 404 error like this........[image]

My code for web.xml is also ver simple :-

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
       <display-name>testing</display-name>
         <welcome-file-list>
           <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
           <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
           <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
           <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
           <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
      </web-app>
```

Comment: yes genius. I meant my question was stupid. Not yours. What else did you try? Did you add your project to the server?

Comment: i am not getting tht wht r u trying to say ??? i just run it through tomcat(the normal option that we get in helios)

Comment: Can you explicitly say what that normal option is?

Comment: Run as ->Tomact server 6.0

Comment: @ChetanWadhwa have you tried exporting your project to a war file and placing it in Tomcat's webapps folder?

Comment: @ChetanWadhwa Also, since we have limited info, it might be beneficial for you to run through steps(4 and up) outlined on http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/eclipse.html

Comment: yeahh, i have tried by exporting it into war file and it worked ........ how is it possible ??

Comment: @ChetanWadhwa I'd run through the steps outlined in the link above. there might be some eclipse integration steps you missed or something.

Answer (score 0):

Include following lines before  `<display-name>` tag  in "web.xml" file, then it'll may help you...

```
   <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
          org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Where you from run this project, through eclipse or through deploy war file on tomcat?